# Do DynamoDB POJOs need to implement Serialized?

Tags: java, serialization, amazon-dynamodb

I am saving a lot of data into Amazon DynamoDB. I am using the `AmazonDynamoDBClient` (and sometimes `DynamoDBMapper`) to perform these tasks.

This is an example illustrating the process:

```
@Data
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Results")
public class Result extends DynamoEntity {

  @DynamoDBHashKey
  private String hashKey;

  @DynamoDBAttribute
  private String period;
  @DynamoDBAttribute
  private String customerId;
  @DynamoDBAttribute
  private double actualCost;
  @DynamoDBAttribute
  private double estimatedCost;

  @DynamoDBHashKey
  public String getHashKey() {
    if (hashKey == null) {
      hashKey = period + "-" + customerId;
    }
    return hashKey;
  }

}
```

And saving the records:

```
private static final AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
private static final DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);

mapper.save(record);
```

Everything works fine, but I am just wondering whether I should implement Serializable to all the POJOs that are being saved into DB (and they are, of course, sent over the network). Is it a good practice or should I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `DynamoDbMapper` works with primary data types like string, int, date etc out of the box. For serialization of complex types, you need to have your own custom marshallers that implement `DynamoDBMarshaller` and use them on your type. If you want to use json, with the built-in `JsonMarshaller`, it should utilize jackson, which doesn't depend on `Serializable` at all.

With the type you mentioned above, I don't think you need it.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so but just wanted to make sure that I am doing the right thing.